# Diagnosing DllNotFoundException when using a native Library from .net UWP app

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, pinvoke, native

I have very little experience doing Windows development and am running into some problems. I have a private third party library that was written in C++. I do not have access to the source code and this library has a number of third party dependancies. The problem is I want to use this application from a CSharp UWP application via PInvoke but I am having trouble so far. I am getting DLLNotFoundException's which I know can be caused if the library cannot be loaded OR any of its dependancies cannot be loaded.

What I have tried so far:
To narrow the problem down, I have tried working from a regular C# Console app (Windows forms also worked). From this startup project, I can call the functions on the library as expected.

Working with the CSharp UWP Test App:
I have compiled a simple c++ test lib that add's two numbers together and used this to be sure I am at least including the main DLL correctly. This works fine for me. I have also read that with UWP apps the DLL"s have to be added directly in the project and marked as content so they are included in the UWP package. I have done this, and confirmed that the non-UWP console application works with the same DLL's.

So my question is this, how come with the same configurations, the Windows console/forms app can work with the library - but the UWP app does not. Is this because the non UWP app can access more of the system DLL's than the UWP app can or something? It would be great if you could at least help me narrow down what the likely problem is. It would be great if there was a way to find out which library('s) the UWP app is not able to load - even though the non-UWP app can load everything fine.

The UWP application I am using is not being deployed to a remote device (yet). I am having the problems while debugging the application locally. Note - I cannot share the library I am using - so posting a test app is out of the question :(.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found the answer to this specific problem. The issue was that I had to also copy in the DLL's that are linked via the Environment variables path. I forgot some of the OpenCV DLL's.

Also useful tools for tracking this down:
In my case I had the library working from the Windows library, so I could use the "listdll" tool that allows you to list the DLL's that have been loaded by a particular process at runtime. I then ran this on the UWP version of the app, after the breakpoint was hit and then could get a rough idea of which DLL's were kinda not loading. I used this in conjunction with "pestudio" that allows you see the required dependancies of an .exe or DLL.